# Can I return a function which have multiple functions in an AngularJS provider?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use like below in an AngularJS provider.

```
provider.files.get();
```

I hope that `files` function could have various functions, such as `put, update, insert, delete, etc.`

my code is below.

but `files.get` is `undefined`

what should I do?

please answer me TT

```
var mod = angular.module('m', []);

mod.provider('provider', function() {

  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      files: function() {
        var service = {
          get: function() {
            console.log('get');
          }
        };
        return service;
      }
    };
  };
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have would allow you to do: `provider.files().get();`

This is because provider.files is a function not an object.

You should change the value of files to the object you've stored in the service variable.

You could also simplify this by using factory instead of provider:

```
mod.factory('provider', function() {
    return {
      files: {
          get: function() {
            console.log('get');
          }
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: if we simplified it to
factory. how can we call
this factory in .config?

Comment: You could not. Factories and services are not available to be injected into a .config block. For more info about this see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers there is a nice grid on the bottom that shows the differences between providers, factories, and services